# How to combine patterns for image renaming?

Tags: python, rename, counting

Sorry if this sounds super confusing: I'm trying to rename some images that are processed in a certain order and I can't figure out how to combine the patterns to produce the correct names. The images are from histological slides and the there are 6 slices on each slide that are imaged, 3 on top and 3 on bottom, and these are labeled with odd numbers. For example, the first slide has slices 1,3,5 on top and 7,9,11 on the bottom. This continues onto the next slide where it goes 13,15,17 and 19,21,23 and so on until it stops at slice 91. These images need to be named in a zig zag order so that I name it as 1,7,3,9,5,11 as this is how the microscope exports the images. Between slides, the number goes up by 2, for example from 11 to 13. The pattern is +6,-4,+6,-4,+6 and +2 when going to the next slide. I'm fairly new to coding and I can't seem to come up with a reasonable way to do this.
I already have the rename function for a sample set I was working with:

```
path = (r"C:\Users\ggabu\Desktop\New folder\preprocessesing\preprocessesing")
i = 0

for i in range(0,7):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename), os.path.join(path,'hTR2Ai-61_s'+ f'{i:03d}'+'.tiff'))
```

I looked into `itertool.cycle` and thought I could use this to repeat this pattern?

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet will print the names in the order you've specified. You would have to modify the loop to interact with the actual filenames in your directory by adding logic to determine the original filename (perhaps based on the order they're listed) and renaming them accordingly using the os.rename function.

```
import os

path = r"C:\Users\ggabu\Desktop\New folder\preprocessesing\preprocessesing"

# Initialize the current slice number
current_slice_number = 1

# Pattern for zig-zag ordering
pattern = [+6, -4, +6, -4, +6]

# Loop over the slides
for slide in range(0, 7):
    # Cycle through the pattern for each slide
    for i in pattern:
        # Construct the filename
        filename = 'hTR2Ai-61_s'+ f'{current_slice_number:03d}'+'.tiff'
        
        # Here you can perform the renaming
        # For example, you can find the original filename based on the current_slice_number or slide number
        # original_filename = ...
        # os.rename(os.path.join(path, original_filename), os.path.join(path, filename))
        
        # Print the filename to make sure it's correct
        print(filename)

        # Update the current slice number based on the pattern
        current_slice_number += i

    # Increment by 2 between slides
    current_slice_number += 2
```

Regarding itertools.cycle, it could be used to cycle through the pattern endlessly, but since you have a well-defined pattern and a fixed number of slides, you can simply iterate through the pattern list as shown above.

Comment: Hi thank you so much! I have a few questions:
- I forgot to mention that I need it to break at 91 and I tried to implement this into the code and it just won't work?
- I also tried it and it skipped from 5 to 13 instead of 5 to 11. This continues for the rest of the numbers indicating that something is weird with the way it switches between slides?
Do you have any ideas?